# GSM device unavailable in NetworkManager

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, networkmanager, gsm

I've been trying for the last few days to set up a GSM connection on my new ubuntu box. However, I can't seem to get Network Manager to manage it correctly. The box is a compulab fitlet2 and the cell card is a simcom 7100A.

```
$ nmcli d

DEVICE    TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
enp2s0    ethernet  connected    enp2s0             
enp3s0    ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
tap0      tun       connected    tap0               
wlp1s0    wifi      connected    MSI WiFi 2.4Ghz    
cdc-wdm1  gsm       unavailable  --                 
lo        loopback  unmanaged    -- 


$ lshw

                 *-usb:1
                  description: Generic USB device
                  product: SimTech, Incorporated
                  vendor: SimTech, Incorporated
                  physical id: 2
                  bus info: usb@1:8.2
                  version: 2.32
                  serial: 0123456789ABCDEF
                  capabilities: usb-2.00
                  configuration: driver=qmi_wwan maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s




$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5af0 (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a84 (rev 0b)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 5a98 (rev 0b)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a9a (rev 0b)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 5ae3 (rev 0b)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5ad8 (rev fb)
00:13.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5ad9 (rev fb)
00:13.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5ada (rev fb)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 5aa8 (rev 0b)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5abc (rev 0b)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5abe (rev 0b)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5ac0 (rev 0b)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5aee (rev 0b)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5ac2 (rev 0b)
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5ac4 (rev 0b)
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5ac6 (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 5aca (rev 0b)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 5acc (rev 0b)
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 5ad0 (rev 0b)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5ae8 (rev 0b)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Broxton SMBus Controller (rev 0b)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)


$ mmcli -m 0

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id '036a0672f2e8521a8489d65396456527879b5df6')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'QUALCOMM INCORPORATED'
           |          model: 'SIMCOM_SIM7100A'
           |       revision: 'M9615A-CETWTBZM-6.0.15255  1  [May 13 2016 01:00:00]'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts
           |                  lte
           |                  gsm-umts, lte'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts, lte'
           |   equipment id: '014339000192712'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.2'
           |        drivers: 'option1, qmi_wwan'
           |         plugin: 'SimTech'
           |   primary port: 'cdc-wdm1'
           |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (at), wwp0s21f0u8u2i5 (net), cdc-wdm1 (qmi), ttyUSB3 (at)'
  -------------------------
  Numbers  |           own : '19708529168'
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'sim-pin2'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (10)'
           |          state: 'searching'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'umts'
           | signal quality: '65' (recent)
  -------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none'
           |        current: 'allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none'
  -------------------------
  Bands    |      supported: 'u1900, u850, eutran-ii, eutran-iv, eutran-v, eutran-xvii'
           |        current: 'u1900, u850, eutran-ii, eutran-iv, eutran-v, eutran-xvii'
  -------------------------
  IP       |      supported: 'ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6'
  -------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: '014339000192712'
           |  enabled locks: 'none'
           |    operator id: 'unknown'
           |  operator name: 'unknown'
           |   subscription: 'unknown'
           |   registration: 'idle'
  -------------------------
  SIM      |           path: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0'

  -------------------------
```

I have been trying to use this network configuration

```
connection.id:                          vzw
connection.uuid:                        a1b6e4cf-8799-4367-8784-1cee2ef1f05f
connection.interface-name:              cdc-wdm1
connection.type:                        gsm
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.timestamp:                   0
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               
ipv4.dns-search:                        
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               
ipv6.dns-search:                        
ipv6.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       0 (disabled)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gsm.number:                             *99#
gsm.username:                           1
gsm.password:                           <hidden>
gsm.password-flags:                     0 (none)
gsm.apn:                                vzwinternet
gsm.network-id:                         --
gsm.pin:                                <hidden>
gsm.pin-flags:                          0 (none)
gsm.home-only:                          no
gsm.device-id:                          --
gsm.sim-id:                             --
gsm.sim-operator-id:                    --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I get this error

```
$ nmcli con up vzw
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

I can't tell nmcli to setup the device either

```
$ nmcli device connect cdc-wdm1
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: gsm: GSM mobile broadband connection requires a 'gsm' setting
```

mmcli -L

```
$ mmcli -L

Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [QUALCOMM INCORPORATED] SIMCOM_SIM7100A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is ModemManager running? What does `mmcli -L` show you? Is your SIM card PIN locked?

Comment: I updated the question to include that command. I don't think that the SIM card would be locked but I'm not sure how you would check that.

Comment: You can follow the steps here to check whether SIM card is locked or not: https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-cellular-connections

Comment: Try this: use "rfkill unblock all" to enable all devices.

Answer (score 2):

From the line 
"Status   |           lock: 'sim-pin2'"
it seems that the card needs PIN before it starts connection.

I had a similar problem, but my message from mmcli -m 0 
was "sim missing" - it explained well all my problems with "device unavailable". The SIM was on place, but there was a contact failure....

Comment: Unless the SIM is configured with additional restrictions, unlocking the ` sim-pin2`  lock is usually not required. It's for things like restricted dialling: you can buy a SIM, use the PIN2 to set up a whitelist of numbers that may be dialled, then put the SIM into your child's phone. The phone and the main PIN will work as usual, but only the whitelisted numbers can be dialed unless you know the PIN2 code.